# Python if else -

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm a beginner of Python's path, need help.
I need all the data to meet all the conditions I set. And if one condition is not met, then he will not print the "else".

That is, if the software prints an error it will not print the "else".
Only if the software meets all the conditions at the end will print the else without "error "messages.

```
from datetime import datetime

data_user = input("Please enter contact details (first name, last name, birth (year), cellular phone number (10 digits) :").split(" ")

if len(data_user) != 4:
   print("Error: the data was entered in the wrong order or there is a missing input or the input is incorrect.")

first_name = data_user[0]
last_name = data_user[1]
phone_number = data_user[2]
birth = int(data_user[3])

if first_name.isnumeric() == True:
   print("Error: the name should contain only letters.")

if last_name.isnumeric() == True:
  print("Error: the last name should contain only letters.")

if len(phone_number) != 10:
  print("Error: the phone number should be 10 digits.")

if phone_number[0] != "0":
  print("Error: the first number should be 0.")

if phone_number.isnumeric() == False:
  print("Error: the phone number most be a number.")

age = datetime.now().year - birth
if age<18:
  print("Error: the year is not suitable.")
if age>100:
  print("Error: the year is not suitable.")

else:
  print("Name:",first_name,last_name, "\nPhone:",phone_number ,"\nBirth:", birth)
```

Comment: throw exceptions or put your code inside a function and return

Comment: Should it print ALL the errors or stop at first ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The easier, to stop at first error, is to use `if/elif/else` construction

```
data_user = input("Please enter contact details (first name, last name, birth (year), "
                  "cellular phone number (10 digits) :").split()

if len(data_user) != 4:
    print("Error: the data was entered in the wrong order or there is a missing input "
          "or the input is incorrect.")
else:
    first_name, last_name, phone_number, birth = data_user
    age = datetime.now().year - birth

    if first_name.isnumeric():
        print("Error: the name should contain only letters.")
    elif last_name.isnumeric():
        print("Error: the last name should contain only letters.")
    elif len(phone_number) != 10:
        print("Error: the phone number should be 10 digits.")
    elif phone_number[0] != "0":
        print("Error: the first number should be 0.")
    elif not phone_number.isnumeric():
        print("Error: the phone number most be a number.")
    elif age < 18 or age > 100:
        print("Error: the year is not suitable.")
    else:
        print("Name:",first_name,last_name, "\nPhone:", phone_number, "\nBirth:", birth)
```

---

To see all possible errors, use a variable to track whether you saw at least one

```
if len(data_user) != 4:
    print("Error: the data was entered in the wrong order or there is a missing input "
          "or the input is incorrect.")
else:
    first_name, last_name, phone_number, birth = data_user
    error = False
    if first_name.isnumeric():
        print("Error: the name should contain only letters.")
        error = True
    if last_name.isnumeric():
        print("Error: the last name should contain only letters.")
        error = True
    if len(phone_number) != 10:
        print("Error: the phone number should be 10 digits.")
        error = True
    if phone_number[0] != "0":
        print("Error: the first number should be 0.")
        error = True
    if not phone_number.isnumeric():
        print("Error: the phone number most be a number.")
        error = True
    age = datetime.now().year - birth
    if age < 18 or age > 100:
        print("Error: the year is not suitable.")
        error = True
    if not error:
        print("Name:",first_name,last_name, "\nPhone:", phone_number, "\nBirth:", birth)
```

Comment: But I need it to meet all the conditions.
If I use "elif" it doesnt pass under all conditions.

Comment: @LiorBenishai You want to see the maximum error possible ?